# How to use OpenGPEG Part 10, JP3D

Tags: jpeg

I have seen some literature that uses the JP3D method in OpenGPEG to compress stereo images, but I have not found any information on how to use JP3D on the official website

I have downloaded OpenGPEG2.3.1. If you can find the usage method or use case, could you please teach me